# Sencha button not working from index.html

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Here is the situation:

When the user open my application he has to log in and it's working.  When he puts the application in background mode I want to show my authentication view again when he comes back. So in my index.html I did the following part in my header :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function onActive() {

   setTimeout(function() {
        Ext.getCmp('mainView').destroy();
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.Authentication'));
        }, 0);
}
</script>
```

My authentication view is showing but if I push my validation button nothing happen (whereas it works when it is the first launch).
Here is my button :

```
{
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Valider:',
width: '150px',
//margin: 2,
cls:'AuthFieldset',
name: 'authent_validateButtonName',
id: 'authent_validateButton'
}
```

Here is my controller :

```
config: {
    refs: {
        btnValidate: '#authent_validateButton',
    },
    control: {
        btnValidate : {
            tap : 'doAuthentication'
        }
    },
},

doAuthentication : function(){
    alert('you\'ve been authenticated'); //the alert does not appear the second time
}
```

I really don't understand ! Maybe my button can't know doAuthentication from my index.html ? it's like my view is not binded to my controller anymore...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your problem, but I know that all application code should be contained within the app.js or any linked .js files(requires:[{}]) and none in the index.html file.  The application has no reference to that outlying code in your index.html file.